# Finding the number of subset pairs of a set

Tags: combinatorics

If a set $S$ has $n$ elements, how many such pairs $(A,B)$ can be formed where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  If you don't insist that $A \cup B = S$, each element has three places it can go:  into $A$, into $B$ or neither.

Comment: Knowing your answers, Ross, and seeing the upvotes, I'm convinced this is a good hint. But for the life of me I cannot see how it works :) I think I'm just not a combinatorics person...

Comment: So would it just be $3^n$?

Comment: @rschwieb:  think about picking up each element of $S$ in turn and putting into one of three boxes.  How many ways are there to do that?  Then the ones you put into first box are $A$, the second $B$

Comment: @user46221:  that's right.  It is like the argument that the number of subsets of $S$ is $2^n$-each element can be in or out.

Comment: @rschwieb: What do you mean "no matter what sets $A,B$ you chose"? It is the very task to count the *ways* to chose $A,B$, not count some number for possibly different choices of $A,B$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see now :) Thanks for the efficient explanation!

Comment: @RossMillikan No, my answer does not suggest that you stop at just one $A$. The obvious implication is that you then have to sum over all $A$. *fix $A$ for a moment* I guess that suggestion leaves the worker grossly open to double counting though... Your answer is obviously the way to go.

Comment: @rschwieb:  I deleted that comment

Answer (score 2):

There are (3<sup>*n*</sup> - 2<sup>*n*+1</sup> + 1) / 2 such pairs of non-empty subsets.

We either put an element in *A*, in *B* or in the *None* bag.
There are 3<sup>*n*</sup> possibilities to do that, but they include the cases where *A* or *B* is empty, the number of these cases has to be substracted from the result.

There are 2<sup>*n*</sup> cases where all of the elements were put in *B* and the *None* bag and *A* is empty, and similarly 2<sup>*n*</sup> cases where *B* is empty. Those 2 * 2<sup>*n*</sup> = 2<sup>*n*+1</sup> cases has to be substracted from the result. There is one case though where everything went to *None*, that one case got substracted twice, so we only have to substract 2<sup>*n*+1</sup> - 1.

Now we are at 3<sup>*n*</sup> - 2<sup>*n*+1</sup> + 1 and have all possible pairs included twice as (*x*, *y*) and (*y*, *x*), so dividing by two gives the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Number of different pairs of non-empty disjoint subsets of a set with *n* elements is:
 (3<sup>*n*</sup> - 2<sup>*n* + 1</sup> + 1) / 2.

Comment: It would help if you offered some reasoning.

Comment: Please look at http://oeis.org/A000392

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the answer above that states $\frac{(3^n-2^{n+1}+1)}{2}$. Consider $S = \{{1,2}\}$, $\{A,B\}$ might be $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ or $\{\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$. But the answer given by this formula for n=2 is 1.

If we consider the order of A and B but A and B may be duplicate sets, then the answer should be
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {n\choose i}3^{n-i} = 4^n-3^n$$
This means to choose $i$ elements as intersection, then for the rest of elements, they have 3 choices: go into A, go into B and go into None.
The situation when the order of A and B doesn't matter is similar to this one. Simply add one(when A and B are universal set) and divide it by 2.

If we do not allow duplicate sets but consider order, then the answer should be
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {n\choose i}(3^{n-i}-1) = 4^n-3^n-2^n+1$$
If we do not consider order, then the answer would be a half of the expression above.

Comment: You appear to have answered hastily, despite the 5+ year history of the Question, and overlooked the condition $A\cap B = \emptyset$.  Perhaps a more relaxed pace in responding to older Questions is advantageous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you consider fixed $A$ for a moment, then $B$ must be a subset of the complement of $A$, and so there are $2^{n-i}$ choices for $B$.