# How many ordered pairs $(X, Y)$, where $X$, $Y$ are subsets of $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many ordered pairs $(X, Y)$, where $X$, $Y$ are subset of $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ are there if $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.  Find an [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216984/finding-the-number-of-subset-pairs-of-a-set), which gives me hint that works, but not $100\%$ sure I can visualize it correctly. it would be $3^5$. The hint says: "Hint: If you don't insist that $A \cup B = S$, each element has three places it can go: into $A$, into $B$ or neither".

What does it mean "if we don't insist that $A \cup B = S$"? Why does that matter?  I can't each element has three choices would end up the same number as $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? This question is a mess, both in content and in formatting. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve formatting.

Comment: If $A\cup B=\emptyset$ then both $A$ and $B$ must be empty.  Did you mean the intersection, $A\cap B=\emptyset$?  Also...are we meant to assume that $A,B=X,Y$?  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: The edit doesn't help.  If $X\cup Y=\emptyset$ then both $X,Y$ are empty.

Comment: I'm almost certain that he means that the intersection is empty

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yeah, maybe...but then later he writes about "if we don't insist that $A\cup B=S$, which suggests that somewhere prior he did insist that the union was $S$.  I'm still guessing that $A,B=X,Y$ and I suppose $S=\{5,6,7,8,9\}$.  But why guess?  The OP really should be able to clarify these issues.

Comment: I made a big edit - OP please clarify if this is what your question is. If it's not I'll revert the edit

Comment: I have edited your post so that it corresponds to the question in the linked post.  In particular, I changed $X \cup Y = \emptyset$ to $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example of what you are describing would be:
$$
X=\{5,6\},\quad Y=\{7,8\}
$$
Then $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ since $X$ and $Y$ share no elements, and $X\cup Y\neq S$ since $X$ and $Y$ does not cover all elements of the base set $S=\{5,6,7,8,9\}$.

---

Another way to formulate this would be to mark each of the elements $5,6,7,8,9$ as either $X$, $Y$ or $S$ where the latter mark is for elements only in $S$ not in the other two. Then we are essentially asking for the number of markings. The marking corresponding to the example from before would be:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
\hline
X & X & Y & Y & S
\end{array}
$$
and since each mark has **three** options $(X,Y,S)$ and **five** digits $5,6,7,8,9$ are to be marked, there will be $3^5$ such possible markings.

Answer (score 0):

5 6
5 7
5 8
5 9
6 7
6 8
6 9
7 8
7 9
8 9

9 8
9 7
9 6
9 5
8 7
8 6
8 5
7 6
7 5
6 5

Looks like 20 to me. Not sure how you get 3^5.

Comment: $5$ choices for $X$, and given this, $4$ choices for $Y$: $$5\cdot 4 = 20$$

Comment: 3^5 should be the right answer. please look at a old post. I am trying to understand it as well.

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it makes sense? What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee edited

Answer (score 0):

Well. Given set having 5 elements.
They are ${5,6,7,8,9}=S$.
Let $X and  Y$ be the subset of $X$.
Power set of $S$ contains $2^5=32$ subsets.

So the the number of order pairs $(X, Y)$ is equal to $32×32=1024$.

Adding the extra contraint $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ and $X\cup Y=S$.
Power set of $S$ having 32 elements in which 16 pairs of sets are mutually disjoint and whose union is equal to $S$.
Thus under these constraint the number of possibility of pairs $(X, Y)$ is equal to 16+16=32.
(16 representing the inverting case, (Y, X)).

Comment: To obtain $X \cap Y$ and $X \cup Y$, type `$X \cap Y$` and `$X \cup Y$`, respectively.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you.